# protobuf-net Merge collection to existing file

Tags: protobuf-net

I have serialized a collection to a file using protobuf-net.

I am looking for a way to merge a few more items to the existing file.

Currently I have this:

```
[Test]
public void CanAppend()
{
    var list = new List<Person>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
       list.Add(new Person {Name = i.ToString(), Age = i});

    using (var file = File.Create("person.bin"))
    {
       Serializer.Serialize<List<Person>>(file, list);
    }

    list.Clear();

    for (int i = 1000; i < 2000; i++)
       list.Add(new Person { Name = i.ToString(), Age = i });

    using (var file = File.OpenRead("person.bin"))
    {
       Serializer.Merge<List<Person>>(file, list);
    }

    using (var file = File.OpenRead("person.bin"))
    {
       list = Serializer.Deserialize<List<Person>>(file);
    }

    //Fails here    
    Assert.That(list.Count, Is.EqualTo(2000));
}

[ProtoContract]
class Person
{
   [ProtoMember(1)]
   public string Name { get; set; }

   [ProtoMember(2)]
   public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

But it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Merge` is  *deserialization* operation (it is used to read a stream as a delta into an existing object). Fortunately, protobuf sequences are simply additive, so all you need to do is open the stream **for append** (or manually move to the end of the stream), and then call `Serialize`.

```
using (var file = File.Open("person.bin", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write)) {
    Serializer.Serialize(file, list);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Marc. 

Great job on protobuf-net btw. I am serializing a massive amount of data and nothing worked for me so far except protobuf-net! Many Thanks!